# Can I connect two organizations of Azure Devops, that are not in the same AAd?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Can I connect two organizations of Azure Devops, that are not in the same AAd? Should I connect the two AADs first?

I actually want to make the Azure artifact feed A as an upstream source in the second organizations. But the feeds are not connecting... The azure documentation is too short. It documents how to connect to other organization feed but not actually explain if I need to connect two organizations or any other prerequisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upstream to a feed in another Azure DevOps organization, both organizations must be connected to the same AAD tenant. A connection between two tenants is not sufficient: the service only checks the two organizations' connected AAD tenant IDs.